# MKCircle overlay not drawn on MapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, dictionary, overlay, mkoverlay

I properly hooked up the MapView to my delegate. Also, the user location does show up on the map, but the MKCircle that's supposed to show up at this same location doesn't do so. It worked at some point, but somehow stopped working. Here is some of my code.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    userLocation = newLocation;
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate radius:500];
    circle.title = @"Nearby sites";
    [worldView addOverlay:circle];
}
```

Comment: Is locationManager a property?  Does didUpdateToLocation get called?  Have you implemented the viewForOverlay delegate method?

Comment: Hi, locationManager is an ivar. didUpdateToLocation get called. And I haven't implemented the viewForOverlay delegate method, which doesn't seem needed according to the documentation.

Comment: So I made my ivar a property, and implemented the viewForOverlay method. And still nothing showed up. And so I then filled my overlay with a color, which worked, making me realize that my overlay was actually being drawn, but was invisible. You can write your comment as answer and I'll mark you as right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With annotations, the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method does not need to be implemented and the map view will draw the default red pin.

But for overlays, you must implement the `viewForOverlay` delegate method.
The map view does not supply a default overlay view.

Comment: I see. Now I understand that it has to be implemented, because overlays don't contain any drawing by default, so they appear invisible. Great, thanks!